# Perl syntax when working with arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

Hi i am studying some code based on arrays and I came accross the following:

```
@array; #contains lines of text

for (0 .. $#array - 2)
{
   #code here
}
```

What is the purpose of the `0 ..` syntax? and what will it do based on the example?
Also how is this different from writing `foreach(@array -2)`?

Comment: Did you mean `foreach(0 .. @array-2)`? If `@array` has 6 elements, `$#array-2` (highest index minus 2) is `3` and `@array-2` (number of elements minus 2) is `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`..` is the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). It can be used in two rather different ways, depending on the context in which it occurs. In this case, you are using the *list* context, in which case your code

```
for (0 .. $#array - 2)
```

is similar to

```
for (local $_ = 0; $_ <= $#array - 2; $_++)
```

In other words, it creates a range of numbers, from `0` to `$#array - 2`.

The range operator can also be used in scalar context, in which case it keeps track of a state. But that is another question.

This is different from

```
foreach(@array -2)
```

Note that in this expression, the array `@array` is put in scalar context by the `-` operator, and will return its size. It will only create one value for the `for` loop, and that is the size of the array minus 2. Say the list has 10 elements, then you get:

```
foreach (8)
```

Which is just a loop over a list of one item (the number `8`), and not very useful. So the difference is quite big, and not meaningful to explain, really. I assume you meant:

```
foreach (@array[0 .. $#array - 2])
```

Which is a loop using an [*array slice*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). In this case, you are looping over the values of the array, rather than over the indexes. E.g.

```
for (0 .. $#array) {
    print $array[$_];
}
```

vs

```
for (@array) {
    print $_;
}
```

You might also note that `for` and `foreach` mean exactly the same thing in Perl. They are aliases of each other, and there is no difference in how they work.